# update row with age calculation with DOB in related table

Tags: join, update, sqlite

SQLite database with a table "events" with a columns *events.eventDate*, *events.ageAtEvent* and *events.foreignKey_participants*, and a table "participants" with columns *participants.primaryKey* and *participants.dob*.

I want to update all rows in events.ageAtEvent with current age at the time of event for each participant.

What I've tried:

```
UPDATE events
SET ageAtEvent = (
SELECT (strftime('%Y', events.eventDate) - strftime('%Y', participants.dob)) - (strftime('%m-%d', events.eventDate) < strftime('%m-%d', participants.dob))
FROM events JOIN participants ON events.foreignKey_participants = participants.primaryKey
);
```

This populates all rows with the same ageAtEvent, presumably the first one. I'm not clear how apply the correct calculation to each row. Very grateful for help on this.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) for what you want to achieve is:

```
UPDATE events
SET ageAtEvent = (strftime('%Y', eventDate) - strftime('%Y', participants.dob)) - (strftime('%m-%d', eventDate) < strftime('%m-%d', participants.dob))
FROM participants 
WHERE events.foreignKey_participants = participants.primaryKey;
```

Comment: Thank you - that does work. But I'm not sure I understand why 'FROM' doesn't include the _events_ table?

Comment: @StamKapetanakis In sqlite, UPDATE FROM implicitly inludes the updated table